# Geopackage Spatial Views in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geopackage

I have created a geopackage with a [spatial view](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html#spatial-views). The first column is a unique rowid that I have aliased as OGC_FID and the second column is a geometry column. When I load this layer into ArcMap 10.4 the query layer user interface appears but no features display after I click OK. I have registered the view in the gpkg_contents table as per the instructions. The same view works for a colleague in ArcGIS 10.6.1.

I even tried simplifying my view by removing any joins. It's a straight select from a single table with geometry. I can add the same table as a layer to ArcMap no problem.

Are spatial views broken or not supported in ArcGIS 10.4?

If not, what was the first version of ArcGIS that supported spatial views?

Comment: In your question, it should be gpkg_contents?

Comment: Try Deleting the cache files (GxDBFactCache.dat, GxObjFactCache.dat) in:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcCatalog

Comment: Thanks @YogeshChavan but deleting that file didn't help.